# How to i display file from JSON object which contains an array?

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc

Below is my json object which is returned. As you can see i have an array called "DocumentVersions" with a blob address of the file that i want to display. On the success function i want to display the image under a div. I tried looping through but i don't know how to display the image. I could have multiple files returned.

```
{
   "FileUploadID":"27",
   "DocumentVersions":[
  {
     "Active":true,
     "DocumentVersionID":"5",
     "FileName":"Logo0112.png",
     "ContentLength":18846,
     "ContentType":"image/png",         "
     "RevisionNumber":0,
     "RevisionDate":"2017-08-01T12:24:04.7748026+01:00",                       
     "Blob":"https://address/documents/75755df4af5f.png",         
     "BlobFileName":75755df4af5f.png"        

  }
   ],
   "success":true,
   "id":"27",
   "message":"The Files have been uploaded"
 }
```

Here is my success function. Where i get a 'Cannot read property 'Blob' of undefined'

```
      myDiv.on("complete", function (data) {

                res = JSON.parse(data.xhr.responseText);

                console.log(res);

                if (res.success == true) {

                    for (var key in res) {
                        var optionhtml = '<p="' + res[key].FileUploadID + 
                      '">' + res[key].DocumentVersions.Blob + '</p>';
                        $(".test").append(optionhtml);

                    }                        
                }
                else {
                    alert(res.message);
                }

            });
```

Comment: can you post jsfiddle of your code?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the DocumentVersions is not a object, it's a array with objects (only one object in this case).

```
    {
   "FileUploadID":"27",
   "DocumentVersions":[

  {
     "Active":true,
     "DocumentVersionID":"5",
     "FileName":"Logo0112.png",
     "ContentLength":18846,
     "ContentType":"image/png",         "
     "RevisionNumber":0,
     "RevisionDate":"2017-08-01T12:24:04.7748026+01:00",                       
     "Blob":"https://address/documents/75755df4af5f.png",         
     "BlobFileName":75755df4af5f.png"        

  }

   ],
   "success":true,
   "id":"27",
   "message":"The Files have been uploaded"
 }
```

You need to specify the inner object in the array that you want to get data:

```
 res[key].DocumentVersions[0].Blob
```

Comment: I even would says that you want to loop through the document version to be able to get all the datas.

Comment: I just an undefined when I do that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, I solved my problem by using the following code this lets me get the image files and display.

```
                        res.DocumentVersions.forEach(function (obj) {
                        var img = new Image();
                        img.src = obj.Blob;
                        img.name = obj.FileName;
                        img.setAttribute("class", "fileLoad");                           
                        $("#fileupload").append(img);
                    });
```